# deal.ii - ParaView "warp by scalar" of my output is not continuous

Tags: finite-element, boundary-conditions, paraview, deal.ii, elasticity

During our finite element course, we've solved the linear elasticity problem in 2D on a square (`GridGenerator::hyper_cube`) with $Q_1$ bilinear finite elements in each component. We imposed neumann homogeneous boundary conditions on one face, and homogeneous Dirichlet on the other three faces.

As outputs, we chose:

- magnitude of the solution $u$
- $u_x$ (x-displacement)
- $u_y$ (y-displacement)

The output of the magnitude of $u$ is the following:
[image]

So far so good. Now, I select $u_x$, and I'd like to warp it by scalar, as it is a scalar valued function. So first let's see $u_x$:
[image]

**Now, I warp this $u_x$ by scalar**, and the plot is the following:

[image]

i.e. it seems that the solution is flat, which is absolutely non-sense. Also, if I increase the scale factor, I got something which to me doesn't make any sense at all:

[image]

Does anyone know if this is normal, or is there something wrong in my finite element solver? If the latter, this would really surprise me

Comment: What is the boundary condition?

Comment: Neumann homogeneous everywhere, except on the left boundary, where is homogeneous Dirichlet. @knl

Comment: $u_x = u_y = 0$ on left? $\sigma(u)n = 0$ on others?

Comment: Where is the loading coming from?

Comment: Exactly. Honestly, those conditions have been given by our teacher. The equation is $- \operatorname{div}(C \nabla u) = -1$, with those conditions. @knl

Comment: $u$ is a vector, so $\nabla u$ is a 2-tensor and $\mathrm{div}(C\nabla u)$ is again a vector. What do you mean by "vector equals -1"?

Comment: @knl It's a typo, thanks. On the r.h.s. I have the vector $[0,-1]$

Comment: Which quantity do you warp by? "Warp by scalar" just means that you choose one scalar field to provide a third dimension to the plot, but there are many quantities that one could choose: The x-displacement itself, the magnitude of the displacement, the size of cells, the distortion of cells, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are using deal-ii for your simulations.  Its a well established fem solver and there is a very less chance that the mistake is with the FEM solver. However, Please check the BC that you have applied to your problem ( In case, if above is not the expected solution )

Try scaling up the data using calculator filter in Paraview and then try “warp by scalar” filter on top of that to verify the plots

Comment: I agree with you for the FEM solver part. As you can see, my BCs are fulfilled: I required neumann homogeneous everywhere, except on the left face, where I have homogeneous Dirichlet. I think the problems comes from the fact that the scalars  that I was using to "warp" were the ones from the estimator, which is one output of my fem solver.

Comment: Please be clear on what you need to ask on the forum , if you find any obervations, edit the posted question immediately.